# Singleton в базах данных. Миф или реальность?

Tags: база-данных, веб-программирование, веб-служба, singleton

Есть веб приложение, основной целью которого являются операции над десятком величин с плавающей точкой. Их количество фиксированное и только изменение спецификации и требований могут способствовать изменению их количества и семантики.

Из данных величин можно собрать полный и осмысленный инстанс для базы данных. И вот в чем вопрос. Стоит ли ради одной записи в БД поднимать всю БД, или же реализовать через io операции с файлами.
За использование базы данных говорит:

1. Оптимизация работы с одновременным доступом к данным
2. Оптимизация кеширования информации

С другой стороны ради одной записи поднимать целую базу.

Кто сталкивался с подобной дилемой поделитесь мыслями\готовыми решениями\неочевидными фактами.

Всем заранее благодарен.

**UPD**
Хранилище нужно(если нет, то очень интересно как), для того чтобы к этим данным обращаться, получать и изменять...

Т.е. вопрос в том, где хранить глобальное состояние в виде массива чисел.

Comment: Ради одной записи - очевидно же не стоит. Файловая система с этим справится на ура

Comment: А причём тут singleton? В целом использовать паттерн singleton нужно очень осторожно. В большинстве случаев он указывает на плохой дизайн.

Comment: @rjhdby Извините, исправил. Должно был быть "количество"

Comment: @MikhailVaysman Возможно я неточно использую терминологию, но объект который в системе только 1, я всегда называл синглтоном. Или это не так(не совсем так)?

Comment: @ВалерийГерасимов если речь идёт про ОО программу, то да - это одиночка. Но и то не стоит его использовать. А в случае БД - этот термин теряет смысл.

Comment: Вы так абстрактно сформулировали вопрос, что очень сложно что либо посоветовать. Попробуйте более подробно описать цели и процессы. Так то по вашему вопросу я вообще не вижу смысла заводить какое либо промежуточное хранилище

Comment: @rjhdby Хранилище нужно(если нет, то очень интересно как), для того чтобы к этим данным обращаться, получать и изменять...
Их всего около 10, и в процессе эксплуатации сервиса их количество не может быть изменено. Вот и вопрос где выгоднее хранить их?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ответ на ваш вопрос зависит от очень большого количество неизвестных факторов.

1. Насколько критичен конкурентный доступ к данным? Допустимо ли, например, грязное или неподтвержденное чтение?
2. Насколько важна скорость извлечения данных? Речь идет об необходимости экономии долей миллисекунд или обращение к сервису идет с мобильника по EDGE, а сами расчеты длятся по пол часа?
3. Насколько часто будут обновляться эти данные? Раз в пол часа по обещанию или, например, непрерывный поток курсов с форекса?

И т.д.

Инструменты подбираются под конкретную задачу. И если где-то под ваши сферические условия в вакууме будет достаточно какой нибудь, прости господи, ардуинки с хранением данных в txt-файле, то при других исходных и какую-нибудь inmemory БД поднять не грех будет.